# Object on req.user Undefined (Node, Express)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to access an array called blockedUsers on a req.user object, however it comes back undefined. There are other arrays and key/value pairs on req.user, all of which I can access without problems.

If I `console.log(req.user);` then I get the following:

```
{ _id: 57ebbdedf814b103c81e0b3d,

  // ... loads of other key:value pairs ...

  lastLogin: 1477934742883,
  __v: 0,
  blockedUsers: [ '57ebcca8f814b103c81e0b4f' ], // This is the one I want to access!
  comMethod: [ 'face to face', 'email', 'whatsapp', 'skype' ],
  photos: 
   [ '/uploads/1fb7f43df2eecafb01138230c6cd87351475067373516.jpeg',
     '/uploads/3398bcddd39be966e8300a8b9f252b181475067373518.jpeg' ] }
```

I can access any of the other properties, but not blockedUsers.

I've tried `JSON.stringify(req.user.blockedUsers);`, and it still comes back undefined.

I've also tried JSON.stringifying the object when I add it to the user in the DB, and I get the same result.

In case it's helpful, here's the bit of code where I add blockedUsers to the user in the database:

```
app.post('/users/block', function(req,res){
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.body.blockingUser, // the id of the user doing the blocking
    {$push: {blockedUsers: req.body.blockedUserId}}, // the id of the user being blocked
    {upsert: true},
    // ... error handling and res.redirect - this all seems to work fine
```

I can't see what the difference is between blockedUsers and the other properties of req.user, and I've checked over and again for typos and other simple mistakes. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: My apologies, but I'm confused, you want to access `req.user.blockedUsers`, but you're trying to stringify `req.body.blockedUsers`, is it just you need to try `req.user` and not `req.body`?

Comment: Ah thanks! That was just a typo - I meant to say "stringify req.user.blockedUsers". I'll update my question.

Comment: `blockedUsers` is an array?

Comment: That's correct @adeneo. `findByIdAndUpdate` is looking for an entirely different `_id`, and that part of my code works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your client-side are passing an array in req.body.blockedUsers, you need to use req.body.blockedUsers[0] for the first index.

If it dont working, you can try use req.body['blockedUsers[]'][0]

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not in req.body. I think I mislead you because of a typo (see the comments on my original post).